# PGP SIGNATURE USING APACHE CAMEL

Tags: apache, cryptography, apache-camel, spring-camel

how to add route to encrypt and sign in PGP format using Apache camel

Comment: this seems off-topic, because it seems server related. Maybe you have more luck on the server-fault board

Comment: no..it is kind of adding sign to a file and persist